# How to insert a text field inside boolean (single on/off) field in node form

Tags: nodes, entities

I have created a a content type and I am using it as a registration form to be created by anonymous users.

When I create a field with type of boolean> single on/off checkbox
for my terms and conditions (where it will display the terms and they will be required to check the single checkbox if they agree).

My problem is i want to add another text field for this particular field type in node form for me to put in the text for terms and conditions.

There is a help text box there which i can use, but i used it to display tooltips.

What is the best way to add another text field to boolean type field in node form?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add a suffix or prefix to your field. The suffix and prefix may contain html.

```
    $form['terms'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="my-class">Something before the field</div>',
      '#suffix' => '<div class="my-class">Something after the field</div>',
    );
```

For a detailed instruction how to write a module that implements hook form alter see [this blog post](http://websmiths.co/blog/very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter).

There is also a module that can add markup widgets to forms. Checkout [Markup](http://drupal.org/project/markup).

Comment: I am quite new to using hook_form_alter. Do i need to copy this code and paste it inside template.php? I just want to add another texfield to boolean field type in node form? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use MArkup because I have conditional field set into this field type. But thanks this module will become very handy

Comment: I've updated my answer.